# angular 4 primeng upload url windows authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, authentication, primeng

I am using File-Upload of PrimeNg and I have windows authentication enabled for my API. now url is generated through constructor using model.id and url becomes

> http://localhost:5200/api/v1/document/:id/Upload

I also have authGuard applied to my components for adding cookie.

> Routes.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    { path: 'factory', component: FactoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'factory/:id', component: FactoryFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'supplier', component: SupplierFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'supplier/:id', component: SupplierFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'businessarea', component: BusinessAreaFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'businessarea/:id', component: BusinessAreaFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'document/:id/Upload', component: EventFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

> HTML code

```
<div *ngIf="model.id">
                    <p-fileUpload name={{model.id}} url={{documentUploadUrl}} (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" (onError)="onError($event)"
                                  multiple="multiple" accept=".txt" maxFileSize="10000000">
                        <template pTemplate type="content">
                            <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
                            </ul>
                        </template>
                    </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

> packages.json

```
 "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "ng2-completer": "^0.2.2",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
```

when i try to upload it gives 401-unauthorized error. any suggestion is welcome.

**Edit**: I can see there is no cookie set when sending request for upload controller but for other urls I can see cookie named "**ASP.NET_SessionId**". I suspect fileupload doesnt have mechanism to add cookie for windowsauth.

**Edit 2**: I have written my own httpclient which i use to add cookies, is it possible to call it through that?

> httpclient.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClient extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        return super.get(url, this.AddCustomOptions(options));
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        return super.post(url, body, this.AddCustomOptions(options));
    }

    put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        return super.put(url, body, this.AddCustomOptions(options));
    }

    private AddCustomOptions(options: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options)
            options.withCredentials = true;
        else
            options = new RequestOptions({
                withCredentials: true
            });

        return options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed Primeng component and Opened a pull request.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2745

introduced new property called withCredentials which will fix it.